# auto-fit columns to their contents with jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

With jqGrid if width of columns are not specified, they share the width of the grid equally. (ie. if the width of grid is 400px and there are 4 columns, they all occupy 100px width). Is there an option to handle this in a smart way so width of the columns can be upon their content?

For example let's say there are two columns: ***name*** and ***info***. Assuming average length of names is **60 chars**, whereas average length of info is **400 chars**. If the grid has a width of **460px**, *name* column should has a width of **60px** and *info* column should has a width of **400px**.

Some kind of autowidth-to-content functionality is needed. I think there is a little possibility about that because if I dynamically resize the grid, then the width columns somehow changes and fits according to their contents.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dynamically resize the grid in the `loadComplete', to make column width better fit the content. Normally I will just choose column widths that are satisfactory for each row and that tends to be good enough. There is also a method for showing an ellipsis for content that is too wide to fit within a column, although unfortunately the technique is error-prone in firefox.